# How to send changing data from asp .net web api

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

Hello The Tittle is Confusing but I don't know the real term for what i want to implement.
Say I have a Client **`MyClient`** and a api **`MyAPI`** . My Api Have a **Get** method named `**LiveData**` to which
**MyClient** is `Subscribed` to. I want to know how to write `LiveData` such that


**LiveData** Sends a new number every second

When New data is send it is shown automatically

It is like a live connection or a messaging app. When new data is arrived in API it is shown 
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

From your question, and what I could understand, it seems like you need a publish/subscribe mechanism where messages are published into a queue and the appropriate consumer/subscriber reads message from the queue. If you are more clear with the question, you might get more help.

Comment: more Like I Have a value in my Server. whose value changes Every 3 sec, I want to update the value in client when ever its value is changed . With out  my client sending a get Req Every 3 sec